# Clearing the screen in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm looking for a way to clean the screen only up to one point without having to redraw all the objects in it again. Is that possible? By "up to one point" I mean if I have 20 objects on screen, each stored in separate buffers, as it stands, each time I want to remove one object I have to clear the entire screen with `glClean` and then redraw the ones left. What I would like is to only remove the last object, without having to redraw the entire thing. The objects are FIFO so there's no ordering problem. I was hoping there is something like pushing a context each let's say 10 objects and only clean/redraw that context instead of all the objects.

Comment: There is no "last object"; there are only pixels on the screen. Remember: OpenGL doesn't know what an "object" is. All OpenGL is is a fancy way of coloring pixels. Once those pixels are colored, it's done. You can't undo that. You can only redo everything *but* that.

Comment: I understand. A usual, my problem could have been avoided if I would have used the right technique (I'm making a drawing software, and I draw using meshes, but I see now that I should draw to textures instead. Thanks anyway for clearing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pixel buffer data containing whatever was 'behind; the object you would like to remove has already been lost from rasterization. You must render the remaining objects again in order to correctly calculate what should have appeared behind the object you removed.